# How to join a local WIFI network using URL

Tags: android, ios, xcode, react-native, android-studio

I am trying to make my Guests connect to my local WIFI network with minimum effort.

1. I tried creating a captive portal on the Tejas Network router but found that I am unable to perform so on my router.
2. Next, I tried to provide a QR code, but for that, every time I need to bring the person the QR code.
3. Now I am trying to perform a connection using a ZXing library-based URL

### Connection URL for QR Codes

```
WIFI:S:My_SSID;T:WPA;P:key goes here;H:false;
   ^    ^         ^     ^               ^
   |    |         |     |               +-- hidden SSID (true/false)
   |    |         |     +-- WPA key
   |    |         +-- encryption type
   |    +-- ESSID
   +-- code type
```

---

when I generate a QR code, based on the above URL, the camera app connects to the Wifi network.

BUT, I WANT TO MAKE THIS AS A CONNECTION STRING, WHICH WHEN A PERSON TAPS ON, WILL CONNECT TO THE NETWORK DIRECTLY.

For example, on this `WIFI:S:<network name>;T:WPA;P:<network password>;;` URL if I try to tap, this feature is not available, so I want to make it a tap on URL which connects directly to the WiFi network.

Comment: You can’t. It is a security/privacy protection. Scanning a QR code is an explicit action taken by the user. Simply clicking a URL on a web page doesn’t have the same level of intent as there are lots of ways a web page can trigger a url without direct action by the user.

Comment: This `WIFI:S:<network name>;T:WPA;P:<network password>;;` is not [valid URL](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738)! This is just format used by QR Code to represent WIFI data. You have to parse this and covert to [proper URL](https://smartjoin.us/rfcs/wifi-url.html) which could be then feed to Adroid API.